# How to set value to "WIFI_DEVICE_OWNER_CONFIGS_LOCKDOWN" setting present in MArshMallow

Tags: android

I tried to set value to `WIFI_DEVICE_OWNER_CONFIGS_LOCKDOWN` in MarshMallow using `SetGlobalSetting API` which is in Device Policy Manager class. But I get a security exception everytime I try to invoke SetGlobalSetting. Actually I am using reflection to call this API. Whenever I try to invoke the method using reflection as given below I get a security exception

`Object o = method.invoke(receiver, args);`

I am not sure what the problem is. One thing I found that SetGlobalSetting API has String parameters. However setting `"WIFI_DEVICE_OWNER_CONFIGS_LOCKDOWN"` expects a integer value. Can somebody help me on this.

Comment: You could use the actual API and be a device owner.

Comment: can you please elaborate a little more. What is the actual API??.

Comment: Actually I cant directly call the SetGlobalSetting API because I have an 2.3.3 environment. Hence i have to use reflection